# How to select the points that belong to the given region?

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, random, mesh

Consider two regions:

```
Vol1 = Region@Cylinder[{{0, 0, -26.5}, {0, 0, 26.5}}, 11.3];
Vol2 = Region@
   RegionProduct[
    Annulus[{1.7, 1.8}, {0.001, 20}, {ArcSin[-(28.7/(2*20))] + Pi/2, 
      ArcSin[28.7/(2*20)] + Pi/2}], Line[{{-26.5}, {26.5}}]];
```

I would like to generate points that belong to the region difference:

```
Vol3=RegionDifference[Vol2,Vol1]
```

However, this is very slow:

```
xxx = RandomPoint[Vol3]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

takes 2 seconds. So I am thinking of generating the points belonging to `Vol2` and then leaving only those not belonging to `Vol1`.

Could you please tell me how to do this? Or maybe it may be possible to speed up generating the random points belonging to `Vol3`.

**Edit**

Maybe I may use `RegionMember`. For the regions Vol1, Vol2, it is even compilable.

Comment: `reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Vol3;
xxx = RandomPoint[reg, 100]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: Try: `getPt[] := (Until[! MemberQ[Vol1, t = RandomPoint[Vol2]]]; t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faster way to get the random points seems at first `RegionDifference` in 2D,then `RegionProduct` to 3D.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg2d = RegionDifference[
    Annulus[{1.7, 1.8}, {0.001, 20}, {ArcSin[-(28.7/(2*20))] + Pi/2, 
      ArcSin[28.7/(2*20)] + Pi/2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 11.3]] // 
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion;
reg3d = RegionProduct[reg2d, Line[{{-26.5}, {26.5}}]];
{reg2d, reg3d, reg3d // Region}
```

[image]

```
pts = RandomPoint[reg3d, 10^4]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]